# Hough transform implementation without line detection

Tags: python, computer-vision, computational-geometry, hough-transform

I am suprised by the fact that I can't seem to find any online implementation of the Hough Transform algorithm as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform). Opencv implements a line detector using the Hough Transform but does not provide any function that performs the transformation into the Hough Space without the line detection after.

So I implemented a naive version myself where seg_map is a numpy array containing `0` and `1`:

```
def hough_transform(seg_map):
   rho_step = 5
   phi_step = 20 * np.pi/180
   n_points_min = 2*rho_step
   diag_length = np.sqrt(seg_map.shape[0]**2 + seg_map.shape[1]**2)
   hough_map = np.zeros( (int(2*np.pi/phi_step),int(diag_length/rho_step)) )

   Y, X = np.where(seg_map>0)
   for x, y in zip(X, Y):
      theta = np.arctan2(y, x)
      r = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)
      for i in range(hough_map.shape[0]):
          phi = i * phi_step - np.pi/2
          rho = r * np.cos(theta-phi)
          if rho>0:
              rho_discretized = int(rho/rho_step)
              hough_map[i, rho_discretized] += 1
   return hough_map
```

However, it's pretty slow (for the inputs I have, the cv2 functions is 200 times faster for the Hough transform + line detection than my Hough Transform algorithm).

So I actually have two questions :

- Did I miss an of-the-shelf *python* algorithm to perform only the Hough Transform without Line detection ? I know that the OpenCV version of the code is open source, but it's implemented in C++.
- Apart from parallelization or non-Python implementation, is there something in my code that is inefficient and should be changed ?

Comment: Part of the problem, besides speed, is that this does not handle vertical lines very well. It's the right idea, but the target cells in the accumulator are better computed as a function of theta, independetly of pixel location

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV is open source. Please, check their code and see how they did implement it. Borrow the code, if needed. The URL is here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv

Comment: Sure, but OpenCV is implemented in C++. I think I was nor clear enough so I edited the question : I'd like a Python implementation (which would not be a wrapper of a C++ implementation)

Comment: If you look at the documentation, you will see it has code for both C++ and Python. A  search in OpenCV documentation for *Hough* lists for both lines and circles. The latter is at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d and https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/d70/tutorial_hough_circle.html

Comment: @fmw42: the implementation is in C++, obviously.

Comment: @fmw42, the code on the pages you shared is only an example of use of the OpenCV functions (which you can indeed call in Python). But it's not an implementation.

Comment: If I was to provide code, I would have posted an answer. I showed you links as an example of what you can find for documentation. You said there was none. The OpenCV documentation for each method shows both C++ and Python methods.

Comment: @fmw42. There's an implication of Java bindings as well. There is no version of the method implemented in Python as far as I'm aware. It's just a wrapper to provide bindings to the compiled C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

You missed [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/). It is an addition to scipy exactly for addtional basic transforms and similar. Specifically, the [`hough_line`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#hough-line) function performs the transform. You can find an example here: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_line_hough_transform.html.

If you do decide to go with [@lennik's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58540500/2988730), the standard Hough transform is implemented in C++ here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp#L163 ([permalink](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/62420b900e53270df54e0affa0c0fb6064ca65dd/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp#L163)). It has the same functionality as the one Cython implementation in scikit image: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/v0.18.x/skimage/transform/_hough_transform.pyx#L245 ([permalink](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/3fb1cc228769229cfeb810270b9d19ac525ded3e/skimage/transform/_hough_transform.pyx#L245)).